# How to Exclude Excel for the Web in manifest

Tags: office-js, office-js-store

Is there a simple method to exclude Excel for the Web (free version of Excel) from the manifest requires for our add-in? We are only supporting Office 365 Online, Excel for iPad and the desktop versions of Excel.

Comment: "Office 365 Online" is an older name for "Microsoft 365 on the Web" and "Excel for the Web" is part of "Microsoft 365 on the Web", so the way your question is worded, it sounds like you are saying both that you do and that you do not want to support Excel on the Web. Please clarify.

Comment: Rick I mean, We are not supporting the version of Excel that is free for users that do not have an office 365 subscription.

Comment: Rick, Let me expand on my initial question by mentioning that the free web version doesn't support functions like "Named Ranges" If we can't block this version easily what about alerting users that the version doesn't support all the features and notify them accordingly.

Comment: Does your add-in have code that assumes that there are named ranges in the workbook? Are you calling `Worksheet.getRange("some-range-name')`?

Comment: Yes. The add-in checks to see if a specific named range is in a specific worksheet

Comment: Is there anyway that you can ensure that all of these workbooks have a range named "x"? (Maybe by having a range with that name in the template from which the workbooks are created.) If so, then you can test for a range named "x" and if there isn't one, then you know your on a host that doesn't support named ranges.

Comment: I suppose this would be possible, thanks.  Are you aware of any other features that are not supported by this version of Excel but are supported in the desktop version?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the manifest to block installation on the free Excel on the Web. However, you might be able to get this effect by using [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment).